# Why is C++ Running Slower than Python?

Tags: python, c++, performance, delay, primes

I recently made a program in Python that calculates the prime numbers under 1,000,000 and puts them in a list, `primelist`. Here it is:

```
import math

import time

max = 1000000

intlist = []

iflist = []

primelist = [2]

sqrt = round(math.sqrt(max))

counter = 3

start = time.clock()

while (counter < max) :

  intlist.append(counter)

  iflist.append(0)

  counter += 2

counter = 0

counter2 = 0


while intlist[counter] < sqrt:



  if (iflist[counter] == 0):


    current = intlist[counter]


    counter2 = counter + current

    while (counter2 < len(iflist)):

        iflist[counter2] = 1

        counter2 += current

  counter += 1



counter = 0


while counter < len(iflist):

  if iflist[counter] == 0:

        primelist.append(intlist[counter])

  counter += 1



print(time.clock() - start)
```

In no way is this program optimized; it's just a basic implementation of the sieve of eratosthenes.

Recently I decided to learn how to code in C++. I wrote a direct translation of my Python code into C++, here it is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    auto start = clock();

    int max = 1000000;
    int squareroot = ceil(sqrt(max));

    int current = 0;

    vector<int> primelist = { 2 };

    vector<int> sieve;

    vector<bool> conditions;

    vector<int> primes;

    for (int n = 3; n < max; n += 2) {

        sieve.push_back(n);

        conditions.push_back(0);

    }

    for (int n = 0; sieve[n] < squareroot; n++) {

        if (conditions[n] == 0) {

            current = sieve[n];

            for (int x = n + current; x < conditions.size(); x += current) {

                conditions[x] = 1;

            }


        }
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < conditions.size(); n++) {

        if (conditions[n] == 0) {

            primes.push_back(sieve[n]);

        }
    }

    /*for (int n = 0; n < primes.size(); n++) {

        cout << primes[n] << endl;

    }*/

    cout << clock() - start << endl;

}
```

From what I've heard, C++ is much faster at number crunching than Python. But, the Python script took 0.74 seconds to run and the C++ script took 13.29 seconds to run(according to the outputs of both)! Why is there such a big difference? Is there something wrong with my code?

I ran the python script with python itself and I compiled and ran the C++ script with Visual Studio 2017. Could Visual Studio be causing this delay? If so, how do I compile and run a C++ program without Visual Studio? I'm having trouble figuring this out.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you testing a debug build or a release build? The debug build is designed for debugging logic and will be hilariously slow.

Comment: And a warning about `vector<bool>`. [it's a weird sucker](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) designed for space efficiency at a cost in many other places.

Comment: ... also, some improvement will result from calling `reserve(max)` on each of your vectors at the beginning.

Comment: ... What he said. `std::vector<bool>` is a snare.

Comment: @user4581301 • should have had a bool_vector that was space-optimized.  :-/

Comment: I got 25ms for a release build, >10s for debug.  I've found the differences much less extreme when not using `std::` collections.  There's various preprocessor flags that can be set in debug builds for `std::` that speed things up.  `ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` is one I'd recommend looking at

Comment: C++ takes 0.01s here (the program reports 0.006s) https://ideone.com/1pK9Wx

Comment: I think I am using a debug build. How do I run a release build?

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

time.clock in python is in floating point seconds

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/

clock in c++ is in clicks, (this varies per machine, but every machine has > CLOCKS_PER_SEC)

in c++ I corrected the output line to

```html
auto t = clock() - start;
cout << ((float)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

for second level output

on my machine the python output is 0.4045815671380151 s and the c++ output is .02s

Comment: I think he understands that

Comment: If he does the same program measures differently on my machine, I will append my times in seconds into this answer. I imagine it is misunderstood because the question mentioned judging by the output of the program, which is not seconds in the c program

Comment: I got similar results in VS to what he was claiming under debug.  `std::` collections are ridiculously slow in debug builds under VS.

Comment: I thought clock() outputs in milliseconds? How do I convert "clicks" to seconds?

Comment: @AnishShanbhag - divide by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, but it's probably ms.

Comment: @zzxyz if necessary you can get better debugging performance from the STL if you disable RTC. I would suggest comparing benchmarks in production environments though.

Comment: @brettmichaelgreen - yeah, that brought my debug time from 16-17s to 4s.  Nice.  I normally don't find benchmarking debug builds useful, but I have several STL apps that are literally too slow to debug under VS.  (They take days to run.)